# how to drop Jlist item on JTable 's Particular row & column in java?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable, jlist

I have a list of items in JList what I want is to drag one item at a time from JList and dropped on particular column the item should be added only that column.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the contents of a particular table cell with the value from a `JList` using drag-and-drop ?

Comment: What is lacking in the [*Default DnD Support*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/defaultsupport.html)?

Comment: no robin,
i have empty Jtable with header and i want whenever item is dragged in column area the item is just added on that column only.

Answer (score 2):

- AFAIK is possible to use [DND in JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) only for `Rows` not `Columns`, because [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) is vertically designed
- example about [DND support for JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/FillViewportHeightDemoProject/src/dnd/FillViewportHeightDemo.java)

Comment: :-) could be correct, but s/he wrote about JList (2D array) to the Column

Comment: Yes, the title says _particular row & column_; the question says _particular column_. @manav: Please clarify.

Comment: btw (if I remember correctly) there are some hacks by [@aterai](http://stackoverflow.com/users/177145/aterai) , maybe he's around and can to post his own answer

Comment: @trashgod yes i want to dropped items only on paritcular cell(row & column) example:
cell 0,1 or 1,1 etc 
if item is dropped on column 0 or 1

Comment: @manav then you have look at another [Demo from Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/BasicDnDProject/src/dnd/BasicDnD.java), but this code supportin DND only in the case that Cell is in Editor Mode as (@trashgod) mentioned, sorry no idea how to properly change cell on DND and mouse hover, is possible, but no idea how to solve correctly without using Thread.sleep() --> really bad practices for Swing GUI, because has a few side effect :-)